# how to find permutation of two lists in prolog

Tags: list, prolog, permutation

if I have two lists in Prolog like

```
people([a, b, c]).
cols([green, red, yellow]).
```

I want to all permutations of theses list like this.

```
?- all triplets(X)

X = [ ((a,green),(b,red),(c,yellow)), ((a,green),(b,yellow),(c,red)), ((a,green),(c,red),(b,yellow)), ((a,green),(c,yellow),(b,red)), ((a,red),(b,green),(c,yellow)), ((a,red),(b,yellow),(c,green)), ((a,red),(c,green),(b,yellow)), ((a,red),(c,yellow),(b,green)), ((a,yellow),(b,green),(c,red)), ((a,yellow),(b,red),(c,green)), ((a,yellow),(c,green),(b,red)), ((a,yellow),(c,red),(b,green)), ((b,green),(a,red),(c,yellow)), ((b,green),(a,yellow),(c,red)), ((b,green),(c,red),(a,yellow)), ((b,green),(c,yellow),(a,red)), ((b,red),(a,green),(c,yellow)), ((b,red),(a,yellow),(c,green)), ((b,red),(c,green),(a,yellow)), ((b,red),(c,yellow),(a,green)), ((b,yellow),(a,green),(c,red)), ((b,yellow),(a,red),(c,green)),((b,yellow),(c,green),(a,red)), ((b,yellow),(c,red),(a,green)), ((c,green),(a,red),(b,yellow)), ((c,green),(a,yellow),(b,red)), ((c,green),(b,red),(a,yellow)), ((c,green),(b,yellow),(a,red)), ((c,red),(a,green),(b,yellow)), ((c,red),(a,yellow),(b,green)), ((c,red),(b,green),(a,yellow)), (p(c,red),(b,yellow),(a,green)), ((c,yellow),(a,green),(b,red)), ((c,yellow),(a,red),(b,green)), ((c,yellow),(b,green),(a,red)), ((c,yellow),(b,red),(a,green))],
```

what i have tried till now is this

```
list_pairs(Pairs) :-setof(p(X,Y),((people(Q),member(X,Q)),(cols(F),member(Y,F))),Pairs).
```

it gives me a list of pairs these two lists like this.

```
?- list_pairs(M),length2(M,L).
M = [p(a, green), p(a, red), p(a, yellow), p(b, green), p(b, red), p(b, yellow), p(c, green), p(c, red), p(..., ...)],
L = 9
```

Comment: Can you what you've tried so far and ask a more specific question about where you're stuck?

Comment: @lurker i have tried this -setof(p(X,Y),((people(Q),member(X,Q)),(cols(F),member(Y,F))),Pairs). and it gives me this result  M = [p(a, green), p(a, red), p(a, yellow), p(b, green), p(b, red), p(b, yellow), p(c, green), p(c, red), p(..., ...)], now i need furthur help beuase i ma stuck here

Comment: Edit your question and put the code that you've tried there, properly formatted.

Comment: @lurkerI have posted to the point I am done .

Comment: The query you designed asks for all pairs. What you seem to be wanting is a list of all pair-wise permutations. So you first need to define a predicate that succeeds for any single pairwise permutation: `pairwise_permutation( P )` where P looks like, for example, `((a,green), (b,red), (c,yellow))`. Then you can do `findall` on that predicate.

Comment: @lurker can you kindly elaborate your comment bit more with some example.please

Comment: @luker can i access any specific element of a pair for example if i have this pair(c,yellow) can i access c or yellow in this pair ?

Comment: Yes, you just unify. If you have `pair(c, yellow) = pair(X, Y)` you will get `X = c` and `Y = yellow`.

Comment: In your example result, you have both `((a,green),(b,yellow),(c,red))` and `((a,green),(c,red),(b,yellow))`. Is that intended?

Comment: @lurker yes it its intended  i am done with this whole code. i only need one more help from you and problem is that i have written this code list_pair(Pairs) :-list_pairs(W),setof((A,B,C),(member(A,W), member(B,W),member(C,W),A\=B,A\=C,B\=C),Pairs).  now i want   each colour only once in my every element of list like (a,green),(b,red),(c,yellow)) . there should be no repetition of yellow,red or green or a,b or c in any signle elemnt of list . like this (a,green),(b,green),(c,yellow)) . now in this element green is coming twice . so i want to only avoid this thing now . how to do this ?

Comment: I'm confused. You're saying there should be no repetition of yellow, red, green or a,b,c, but your example desired output shows repetition. For example, in the list that you say you want your results to look like you have `((a,green),(b,red),(c,yellow))` and you have `((a,green),(c,yellow),(b,red))`.

Comment: @lurker yes luker there should be no repetition of a,b or c or red, yellow or green in single element of list . for example single element of list is like ((a,green),(b,red),(c,yellow)). there are many such elements in list. but in one element their cant be more than one pair with a,b or c or red,yellow or green . for example this single elemnt of list ((a,green),(b,red),(c,yellow)) contain only 1 a,b, and c and red,green and yellow but this single element of list ((a,green),(a,red),(c,yellow)) contain 2 'a'.one in pair with green and one in pair with red . now i only want to avoid this thing.

Comment: The answer I posted complies with that requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Without just giving away a whole answer,  if you really are looking for a matching, element-to-element of permutations of each list, then you'd want something like:

```
match_perm(List1, List2, MatchUp) :-
    permutation(List1, PList1),
    permutation(List2, PList2),
    zip(Plist1, PList2, MatchUp).
```

`permutation` is a predicate already in the Prolog library. You'd need to write a predicate `zip` that takes two lists and just pairs up the corresponding elements. `zip([a,b,c], [1,2,3], MatchUp)` would yield `MatchUp = [(a,1),(b,2),(c,3)]`. If you really want `((a,1),(b,2),(c,3))` instead, that's a bit more work since `(...)` isn't a list form in Prolog.

Once you have `match_perm`, then you'd use `findall` on that.